# Protect the Serializeable File from Copying (Java Program)

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Java Program that have expired date and can only be used X times . The expired date and X times is read from serializable file . I have encrypted the file with DES . The problem is how to protect that file from copying that file ?

Example problem : First time , User A have my program with Data.ser (A)that contain value how many times he can open my program (50 times) . Then he copy Data.ser (A) to other folder to save that Data.ser(B). After he using my program 49 times , then he/she copy Data.ser(B) to replace Data.ser(A) so can open my program 50 times again . How to prevent that  ?

Now i only hide the file in separate folder (Like in C:\Windows\rds) . But if user find that file . User can copy that file .

Is it there is a way to secure that Serializeable File ?
Or there is better way to save that expired date and how many times can be opened for that Program ?

Thanks ...

Comment: If I recall correctly you encode in the file itself when it was last accessed. A copy will have the wrong timestamp. I remember it being discussed somewhere, but I can't immediately find the link

Comment: But the first rule of securing your software against piracy is that it will be pirated; don't make your legitimate customers suffer to avoid that: Customers should find it easy, stupid pirates should find it hard, don't worry too much about clever pirates

Comment: And always remember that the objective isn't to prevent people from using your software, it is to get them to pay for it.